# Для чего нужны методы с приставкой static?

Tags: javascript, static, prototype

Как я понимаю они нужны что бы ограничить прототипирование и наследование функции или метода далее, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Ну, лучше не объяснить https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы с "приставкой" `static` добавляются непосредственно в класс, а не в объект класса, либо прототип:

```js
class AClass {
  constructor() {
    this.aCon = function() {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  a() {
    return 1;
  }
  static aStatic() {
    return 2;
  }
}

var aObj = new AClass();
console.log(aObj.hasOwnProperty('aCon'), aObj.hasOwnProperty('a'), aObj.hasOwnProperty('aStatic'));
console.log('aCon' in aObj, 'a' in aObj, 'aStatic' in aObj);
console.log(aObj.aStatic);
console.log(AClass.aStatic);
```

Comment: @mbfilipp, потому что [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) проверяет наличие свойства **непосредственно** в объекте, в оператор `in` также проверяет в прототипе, так как метод `a` расположен в прототипе  _`aObj.hasOwnProperty('a')` возвращает `false`_, а _`'a' in aObj` возвращает `true`_

Comment: Спасибо большое! (уже прочел про эти два метода)